# getArtefact return NULL for the "Domain"

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I am new to Grails and was trying to follow with the examples in "Beginning Groovy and Grails"

When I was trying out the examples, I had the following issue:

```
domainClass = grailsApplication.getArtefact("Domain", domainClassName)
```

The domainClass was returning NULL. But when I use the following snippet, I get the correct Class.

```
if (!domainClass) {
        def artefacts = grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")
        domainClass = artefacts.find {item ->
            item.name == domainClassName
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with the first part? Is there anything else that I need to take care of. I downloaded the example code of the book and I haven't seen any other specific changes.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: try to use  domainClassName without package prefix

Comment: @Jenk: Thanks for the reply!!! I am using the domainClassName without the package prefix. I am intact getting it from the params like below:    domainClassName = capitalize(params.domain)
  domainClass = grailsApplication.getArtefact("Domain", domainClassName)

Comment: analyze your capitalize method. i suppose it uppercases your real classname may be.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path of the domain class i.e prefix the package.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet works too, the domainClassName just needs to be fully qualified name ie packagename.domainclassname

```
def domainClassName  = 'org.abc.Sample'   
def domainClazz = grailsApplication.getArtefact('Domain', domainClassName)
```